# How to generate HATEOAS links for paging in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API controller to return in Link header?

Tags: url, pagination, asp.net-core-webapi, hateoas, link-header

I need to create HATEOAS pagination links for first, last, next, and previous and add them to the `Link` header of the response.

A `PagedResultDTO` is returned from the application layer to the controller in the API layer. Besids the records it holds information about `TotalCount`, `PageNumber`, `PageSize`, and `PageCount`.

I'm confused with the options provided by the framework. Many posts use `UriHelper`, but it seems that `LinkGenerator` is the newer and the current helper class. Looking at the documentation I don't understand the difference of the various methods that `LinkGenerator` provides. Is there any good post that explains the use cases for the various methods?

Since a request can have various other query parameters e.g. for sorting, filtering, searching, embedding they need to be kept and returned when the links get created. E.g. a controller declaration can look like:

```
public ActionResult<PagedResultDTO<GetCountriesDTO>> GetCountries(
   [FromHeader(Name = "If-None-Match")] string? eTags, 
   [CommaSeparated] IEnumerable<string> languages, 
   string? sort, 
   string? search, 
   int? pageNumber, 
   int? pageSize)
```

(`[CommaSeperated]` is an extension that accepts multiple values separated by comma and creates a List without having to repeat the query parameter. If pageNumber and pageCount are not set and don't have default values set in a specific controller method my use case handlers will set default values.)

For a request like:

```
GET https://example.com/api/countries?languages=de-DE,en-US&sort=name
```

I need to generate:

```
<https://example.com/api/countries?languages=de-DE,en-US&sort=name&pageNumber=2&pageSize=20>; rel="next",
<https://example.com/api/countries?languages=de-DE,en-US&sort=name&pageNumber=1&pageSize=20>; rel="first",
<https://example.com/api/countries?languages=de-DE,en-US&sort=name&pageNumber=10&pageSize=20>; rel="last"
```

All query parameters not related to paging need to be kept in the generated links. Does `LinkGenerator` support a straightforward way to generate those pagination links? Is there any structure that supports the `Link` header format already? I wonder if should just create the links manually using the `Request` object?

Answer (score 1):

I created now my own code using a dictionary that holds the passed query parameters.

```
Dictionary<string, string> query = new();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, StringValues> item in httpContext.Request.Query)
{
    query.Add(item.Key, string.Join(",", item.Value));
}
```

I then update `pageNumber` and `pageSize` for each link. If it was not set before and defaults are used the parameters are added, e.g.:

```
query["pageNumber"] = "1";
query["pageSize"] = pageSize.ToString();
```

I then use `LinkGenerator` to create the link:

```
linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(httpContext, values: query)
```